# Channel close fees too low

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, lightning-network-daemon, fee-estimation, ln-closing-channels

I closed a lot of channels in recent days - but for some of them I left the confirmation fee too low. I'm hoping the mempool will clear in the coming week and they will confirm.

Is there a way to speed up the closure process - or even force close them? I tried to force close two of them but it hasn't worked - they remain 'waiting close'. Also - running 'lncli pendingchannels' shows that those two channels now have a 'ChanStatusBorked' status flag. Also tried RBF using 'wallet bumpfee' command on one of the 'anchor' channels - but that also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You may be able to reach out to the other party and have them initiate a force-close on their side. I had to do this once, they did not listen to my emails so a developer actually helped me reach out to them and they did the force close eventually which I am still grateful for.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the solution: just needed to learn how to properly use the lnd command 'wallet bumpfee' that can be used on cooperative close TXIDs that have confirmation fee set too low. Also note that there is a wallet bumpclosefee command for bumping force close commitment transactions - noting that this is only available on 'anchor' channels which can be looked up with the pendingclose command.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to manually create another closing transaction with a higher fee, but you will need to reach out to your channel partner for them to cosign it. This is because a mutual close transaction spends from the funding output, which is a 2-of-2 multisig between the two parties.